# CSRF-attack using Django

Tags: django, security, csrf

I'm working on a Django project and I can make a CSRF-attack from an external url or file. How I can block it?

The attack consist:

1. I create a file with this content:

```
<html>
   <body>
   <script>history.pushState('', '', '/')</script>
   <form action="https://XXXXXX.com/YYYYY/AAAAAA/LLLLLL">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

2. I login on my page
3. I open the file in the same browser
4. Submit the button

The request is accepted and the action is executed.

Thanks for everything :)

### Solved

`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` does not provide csrf protection if the request is `GET`

```py
# Assume that anything not defined as 'safe' by RFC7231 needs protection
if request.method not in ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE'):
    if getattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', False):
        # Mechanism to turn off CSRF checks for test suite.
        # It comes after the creation of CSRF cookies, so that
        # everything else continues to work exactly the same
        # (e.g. cookies are sent, etc.), but before any
        # branches that call reject().
        return self._accept(request)
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem with Django? <br><br>
I also had to deal with CSRF-attacks, this doc was very useful to undestand the vulnerability and ideas on how to solve it: [Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) Additionally I found this Django middleware which seems to be pretty easy to implement. Check this out! [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to post and add csrf token

```
<html>
   <body>
   <script>history.pushState('', '', '/')</script>
   <form action="https://XXXXXX.com/YYYYY/AAAAAA/LLLLLL" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}

       <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

and handle your view inside :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     # your logic here
```

Make sure  that 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' should come before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with.